# How can I shorten this python code thats using random?

Tags: python

How can I shorten this code so it has same functionality?

```
from random import *
    
throw1 = randint(1,6)
throw2 = randint(1,6)
throw3 = randint(1,6)
throw4 = randint(1,6)
throw5 = randint(1,6)
throw6 = randint(1,6)

print(throw1, throw2, throw3, throw4, throw5, throw6)

if throw1 == throw2 == throw3 == throw4 == throw5 == throw6:
    print(throw1 + throw2 + throw3 + throw4 + throw5 + throw6 + 100)
else:
    print(throw1 + throw2 + throw3 + throw4 + throw5 + throw6)
```

Comment: Improving existing code is more appropriate on [codereview.se]

Comment: And anyway, *"How can I shorten this code so it has same functionality?"* - use lists...

Comment: Whenever you start to create variables with a name sequence (…1, …2, …3, …) there's a high change you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

without using any other modules:

```py
>>> import random
# k == number of dice rolls
>>> throws = random.choices(range(1, 7), k=6)

>>> print(*throws)
5 5 6 5 3 6

>>> print(sum(throws) + (100 if all(throws[0] == t for t in throws[1:]) else 0))
30
```

Comment: Alternatively: `min(throws) == max(throws)`

Comment: has to iterate over the entire list twice in all cases. `all` just once in the worst case (early stopping)

Comment: Or `print(sum(throws) + [0, 100][len(set(throws)) == 1])`

Comment: @StefanB Your version also has to iterate twice since you take a slice (`throws[1:]`). I wouldn't worry about it either way, since it's still O(n) with a very small *n*. I bet me tying this comment took more time than if we ran any of the proposed answers on this page hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: Mhm just did it for the intuition; `all(throws[0] == t for t in throws)` would probably even be "faster" ^^

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the goal is, but I would store the throws in a list for a start:

```
from random import *
throw = [randint(1,6) for _ in range(6)]

print(*throw)
if len(set(throw))==1:
    print(sum(throw)+100)
else:
    print(sum(throw))
```

Comment: Also, the change that all throws are equal is really small. Something like (1/6)^5.

Comment: `sum(throws) % 6 == 0` is an insufficient condition `[5 5 6 5 3 6]` would also fulfill it.

Comment: True, fixed it. I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like list comprehension and `itertools.groupby` could be useful here.

```py
from random import randint
from itertools import groupby

# generate 6 random integers
throws = [ randint( 1, 6 ) for _ in range( 6 ) ]

# group values in throws
groups = itertools.groupby( throws )

# if all elements are equal, only one element will exist in the groups
score = sum( throws )
if len( groups ) == 1:
  print( f'All elements are equal. Score: {score + 100}' )
  
else:
  print( f'Not all elements are equal. Score: {score}' )
```

Comment: The use of lists or `itertools` depends on how long your lists will be. @Stefan B's answer seems more suited if the lists are short.